# Create loop but want to fetch one each row in the one tag <NameValueList> and start another in the loop

Tags: php, sql, database, loops, while-loop

I am tried to create loop which fetch 2 different values from database and put in one tag  each value.

For example **Name**: Colour,Size and **Value**: Red, pink in Database

```
<?
//DATABASE CODE HERE//
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM variation WHERE usr='Test'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<Variation>\n";
  echo "<VariationSpecifics>\n";

$options1 = explode(',',$row['val']);
foreach($options1 AS $option1)
{
 echo "\n\n<NameValueList>\n";
 echo "<Name>" . $row['name'] . "</Name>\n";
 echo "<Value>$option1</Value>\n";
 echo "</NameValueList>\n\n";
 }
}
  echo "</VariationSpecifics>\n";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I found above small script but it shows value separate and want like this -

```
  <Variation>
    <VariationSpecifics>

      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Size</Name>
        <Value>S</Value>
      </NameValueList>

      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Color</Name>
        <Value>Pinks</Value>
      </NameValueList>          

    </VariationSpecifics>
  </Variation>

  <Variation>
    <VariationSpecifics>

      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Size</Name>
        <Value>M</Value>
      </NameValueList>

      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Color</Name>
        <Value>Red</Value>
      </NameValueList>          

    </VariationSpecifics>
  </Variation>
```

Please help.

Comment: Value 2 is Red and Pink, but they are both color, is there any mistake in the example or my misunderstanding

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Value1 is <Name>color<Name> and Value2 is <value>Red<value> and i want to fetch in each value in separate or combine in one tag. is that make sense.